# Web Macro to Python (Selenium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

a year ago, I was using an a macro to record my actions on the web and then converting them to a python selenium script. Now I want to do that again but cant find the add-in or plug that allowed me to do this. Essentially I clicked the record button and it ran in the background recording my clicks and then sent it to a python script.

I remember it required me to download an older version of Firefox to work properly. 
I need this it allows to be record a task and then piece together multiple instances into a full fledged script.

Does anyone know a program that converts a web macro into an actual python script that I can edit and use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Maybe by this time you found out what add-in it was you used? I am looking for a similar tool so very curious!